# Designing A 2-Way SSL RESTful API

Tags: api, rest, wcf, api-design, ssl

I am starting to develop a WCF API, which should serve some specific clients.

We don't know which devices will be using the API so I thought that using a RESTful API will be the most flexible choice.

All devices using the API would be authenticated using an SSL certificate (client side certificate), and our API will have a certificate as well ( so its a 2 Way SSL)

I was reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7551/best-practices-for-securing-a-rest-api-web-service) question over SO, and I saw the answers about authentication using Basic-HTTP or OAuth, but I was thinking that in my case these are not needed, I can already trust the client because it possesses the client-side certificate.

Is this design ok? 
Am I missing anything?

Maybe there's a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [mutual authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_authentication) is always better than username/passwords as long as you have the appropriate cert management system in place and it's properly managed.  Your management system should provide for an easy way to issue or revoke a cert.

Comment: what does this management system do? should it be delegated to an IT administrator or something of the sort? I am weary that no one will know how to manage it in the future and this will become too much of a single point-of-failure

Comment: A management system is there to manage the validity of the certs.  Certs can be issued, expire, and be revoked.  Management deals mainly with revocation, CAs usually deal with issuing the cert.  Some software have both bundled up for ease of management.

Comment: This should not preclude a username and password though, or something else.  Two factor would be better than single factor.